# How to responsive inner image using canvas

Tags: css, canvas, bootstrap-modal

As per my project requirement I have to make this canvas responsive.

```
        Canvas code:        

<div style="width:100%; height:auto; clear: both; position: relative; left: 7%">
                        <canvas id="wheelcanvas" width=440%; height=450%; 
                            style="z-index: 1;width:100%; "></canvas>
                        <div id="singlechance"  
                            style=" width: 100%; height: 80%;  background: transparent url('images/123.png') no-repeat center; z-index: 4; position: absolute; top: 7%; left: -2.1%">
                            </div>

                    <div id="single"
                            style="width: 100%; height: 80%; background: transparent url('images/arrow3.png') no-repeat center; z-index: 4; position: absolute; top: -37%; left: -3.0%">
                            </div>


                    </div>
```

How to make responsive

```
<div id="singlechance"  
                                style=" width: 100%; height: 80%;  background: transparent url('images/123.png') no-repeat center; z-index: 4; position: absolute; top: 7%; left: -2.1%">
                                </div>
```

and

```
<div id="single"
                                style="width: 100%; height: 80%; background: transparent url('images/arrow3.png') no-repeat center; z-index: 4; position: absolute; top: -37%; left: -3.0%">
                                </div>
```

Comment: @kukkuz sorry sir.